# why I am getting exceeded your quota Error with YouTube Data API

Tags: python, google-api, google-oauth, youtube-data-api, google-api-python-client

I am trying to use youtube data API to access public data, i.e., the popular videos in a region. I am having a problem with the request. Every time I use the JSON file, I get a URL to visit and I have to copy and paste code to my terminal to process the request. This is not what I need. After reading few answers on stackoverflow, it seems like since I am accessing public data, I have to removed these two lines of code:

```
flow = google_auth_oauthlib.flow.InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(client_secrets_file, scopes) 

credentials = flow.run_console()
```

and added this line:

```
youtube = googleapiclient.discovery.build(api_service_name, api_version, developerKey=API_KEY)
```

with my API_KEY credentials!, however, I am making the first request with the API and I am getting this error!

```
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet%2CcontentDetails%2Cstatistics&chart=mostPopular&maxResults=10&regionCode=US&pageToken=&key=A...&alt=json returned "The request cannot be completed because you have exceeded your <a href="/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota">quota</a>.". Details: "[{'message': 'The request cannot be completed because you have exceeded your <a href="/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota">quota</a>.', 'domain': 'youtube.quota', 'reason': 'quotaExceeded'}]"> $
```

note that I set the maxResults=10, in my request. Any idea why? many thanks for the help in advance!

```
request = youtube.videos().list(
        part="snippet,contentDetails,statistics",
        chart="mostPopular",
        maxResults=10,
        regionCode=location,
        pageToken=accessToken
    )
```

Comment: Pay attention **not to put your API key in your question**. Otherwise have you tried to just wait without using your quota for something else ? According to https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/youtube.googleapis.com/quotas, "Daily quotas reset at midnight Pacific Time (PT)." if you still experience the bug in 48 hours, let me know. And check that there isn't any quota usage from _for instance someone using your API key because you shared it..._ 

Comment: Thank you @BenjaminLoison for the reply. I just had to wait for 24hrs and it worked! and thank you for mentioning the API, I did reset the API key so this should be useless.

Answer (score 1):

I just had to wait 24 hours and the API key worked by itself. However, you should go to IAM & Admin then select Quotas. Make sure your project
YouTube Data API v3 Queries per day is set to 10,000. If not, delete the project and recreate another project.